# How do I use date_select without a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date

I have a form that I want a date in. The date that the controller defines is @date_end. I want this date in the form, but without an AR model this seems REALLY STUPIDLY hard. I used to use this:

```
  = date_select :date_end_, nil, :default => @date_end
```

But this only works if your 'name' is different from the instance var. If they are the same you get an 'interning string' error.

The only way I've found to solve this is to add a method to Object to return self

```
class Object
  def get_self 
    self 
  end
end
```

Then I can do:

```
  = date_select :date_end, :get_self
```

But we all know this is stupid. But there doesn't seem to be another way...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this do the trick:

```
= select_date Date.today, :prefix => :date_end
```

According to [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), under section "4.1 Barebones Helpers", using this particular helper will create a series of select tags for the day, month year. The names should end up looking like "date_end[day]", "date_end[month]"...etc. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Or at least not prominent enough.

Comment: That's the wonderful world of rails, where the best features are subtly documented.:) Glad I could help.